# Remove unwanted part of String. Regex / JS

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string which looks like this:

```
var myString = '73gf9y::-8auhTHIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT'
```

What regex would I need to end up with:

```
'THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT'
```

The first part of my String will always be a random assortment of characters. Is there some regex which will remove everything up to `THIS`?

Comment: @anubhava Nope. Upper or lower. I don't mind.

Comment: has the random part a fixed length?

Comment: @micha no, no fixed length.

Comment: @Daft What is the pattern of the texts you want to remove and the texts you want to keep? If the texts you want to keep all CAPS and separated by _? What is the separator of the "to keep" texts and the "to remove" texts?

Comment: Only an oracle can help you then.

Comment: @jrarama yes jrarama. That's correct! Sorry, I wasn't sure what you meant by _pattern_.

Comment: @Daft When I say __pattern__  I mean are they alpha numeric? Does it starts with a specific texts? Are they alpha numeric? Regex is used to search and match pattern so if you don't have patterns you can't use regex

Comment: has your random key part small letters,digits and special chars and the part you want keep  big letters and _   ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So you want to strip out everything from beginning to the first uppercase letter?

```
console.log(myString.replace(/^[^A-Z]+/,""));
```

> THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37c3stj5/), well I'm not sure if that is what you want :)

---

To strip out everything from start to the first occuring uppercase string, that's followed by `_` try:

```
myString.replace(/^.*?(?=[A-Z]+_)/,"");
```

This uses a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). See [Test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dB9tX9/2);

Answer (score 7):

Going by the input, you can use `match`. The character class `[A-Z_]` matches any capital letters and `_` (Underscore) and `+` quantifier along with `$` anchor matches the character class till the end of the string.

```
myString = myString.match(/[A-Z_]+$/)[0];
console.log(myString); // THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT
```

Comment: Sorry, what will that expression give me back?

Comment: @Daft it will give you `THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Amit Joki's excellent solution (sorry I don't have the rep yet to comment): since `match` returns an array of results, if you need to remove unwanted characters from within the string, you can use `join`:

```
input = '(800) 555-1212';
result = input.match(/[0-9]+/g).join('');
console.log(result); // '8005551212'
```